# Global variable used to store filter data for route is getting overwritten; How to to make it store the data?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

Facing a small blocker with the useRouter in Nuxt3. The blocker is am trying to update my router wrt filter's "key" and "value" on  a click on the filter's checkbox and am getting the output but not as expected.

I need to store all my checked values in a global `variable("filterQuery")` as object and render them on route but as I click on different filter the global variable data preset in over written wrt the change on "key" and am getting the latest selected filter data on my route.

What is the best practice I can follow here?

```
// Function to push filters value to route
const router = useRouter();
const filterQuery = {};
const filterValues = (event, option): void => {
if (!filterQuery[option.key]) filterQuery[option.key] = new Set();

 event.target.checked ?
  filterQuery[option.key].add(option.slug)
  : // Remove the key from query
  filterQuery[option.key].delete(option.slug);
  const newQuery = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(filterQuery))
  newQuery[key] = Array.from(filterQuery[key]).join(",");

  console.log(newQuery);
  router.push({ query: newQuery });
};
```